# Why doesn't my WPF application free up its memory?

Tags: c#, wpf, memory

I don't understand why my test WPF application here doesn't free up the memory it uses after I have closed the MainWindow and set it to null, and even run the garbage collector?

In the beginning, even before the MainWindow is created, the Application takes almost no memory, about 5 MB, but when I create the first window it takes 43 MB and it stays there for the rest of the application's life. Isn't it possible to get it back down to 5 MB again without restarting the application?

[Diagnostic Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cF3aQ.png)

```
public App()
{
    ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;

    DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
    dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);

    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    dispatcherTimer.Start();
}

private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MainWindow == null)
    {
        MainWindow = new MainWindow();
        MainWindow.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        MainWindow.Close();
        MainWindow = null;

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

Comment: WPF and the .NET framework get to decide when to collect certain objects, and there's some caching going on in there somewhere.  `GC.Collect` isn't a guarantee, even if you call it twice.  In short, this is something you shouldn't be worrying about; the garbage collector is far smarter than you and I.

Comment: Why does it even matter if memory is released to the OS?

Comment: With a .NET application, the way to measure memory usage is with Performance Monitor and the .NET Memory counters.  Think about it.  If, while the app is running, the memory system allocates 43 meg of virtual memory and the GC runs, the app isn't going to release that back to the OS unless there's a reason - it can just reallocate that same memory over and over as part of the `new` object / GC cycle.

Comment: It quite normal for applications to release their memory when it's not in use and it's not in use when the MainWindow is closed. The problem is that it scales up for larger WPF applications to that's why I'm asking the question.

Comment: What is your actual memory requirement?  The WPF application I work on uses between 1GB and 4GB during normal operation, but it runs on ordinary PC equipment, not Arduinos.

Comment: The requirement isn't about how much memory it uses, but how to release it and still hold the application running for X number of hours, and restart is not an option. Basically what I want is to know how to make it go Idle in a state as when I just started the application.

Comment: @AndersB is right. You could try to stress your system by allocating some 20+ GB in another process (reading+writing to the memory is important) and see if the OS decides to free your App's memory.

Answer (score 1):

You have a memory leak, so the `GC` will not be able to collect your `MainWindow`. You must unsubscribe from your event handler. So keep the timer in a backing field:

```cs
MainWindow = null;
// Add this:
this.dispatcherTimer.Tick -= new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
this.dispatcherTimer.Stop();
```

Comment: dispatcherTimer.Tick is holding onto the Event delegate, not the MainWindow.  MainWindow should go out of scope when `dispatcherTimer_Tick` exits.

Comment: It doesn't cause a memory leak you can make the same test without the DispatcherTimer just open and lose the MainWindow and set it to null will give the same result.

Comment: Fair enough. You still have a leak though. Better fix that to avoid confusion regarding memory not being freed.